# Tuning fuzziness to improve search results in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to improve my search results with the fuzziness parameter, however, I have a very language specific issue:

In Spanish, many female names and words just add an "a" at the end of the male version of the word, when I search for a female name like "Daniela" with fuzziness set to auto or 1, I get returned "Daniel" as a result, I'd have to type "Danielaa" for the search to match "Daniela"

Any help on this issue?

Comment: Why not return both and let the user choose which is the right answer?

Comment: I thought about it, however, suggesting "Daniel" when the user searched for "Daniela" is not the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is prefer exact matches over fuzzy matches. As fuzzy queries [aren't scored](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/fuzzy-scoring.html) like ordinary queries, you'll need to handle this yourself.

I've tackled this in the past by using a bool query with two `Should` clauses - one for boosted, non-fuzzy query and another for the fuzzy query.

Something along these lines (untested so may need some tweaking but should illustrate the idea):

```
{
    "bool" : {
        "should" : {
            "match" : { "name" : { 
                "query" : "kimchy",
                "boost" : 2
            }}
        }, 
        "should" : {
            "match" : { "name" : {
                "query" : "kimchy",
                "fuzziness" : "auto"
            }}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's going to require some adjustments but overall it will do the trick. Thanks!